# Why I get error in angularjs project tutorial?

Tags: angularjs

I work on my AngularJS tutorial.

I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module sensorManagement due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
minErr/<@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:68:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:4264:19
getService@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:4411:39
invoke@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:4443:1
runInvokeQueue@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:4358:11
loadModules/<@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:4367:11
forEach@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:336:11
loadModules@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:4348:5
createInjector@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:4274:11
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:1630:20
bootstrap@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:1651:1
angularInit@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:1545:5
@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:28361:5
trigger@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:2998:7
createEventHandler/eventHandler@http://localhost:7486/Scripts/angular.js:3273:9
```

Here is my module definition:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var myApp = angular.module("sensorManagement", ["ngResource"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Courses', { templateUrl: '/templates/courses.html', controller: 'CoursesController' });
            $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Instructors', { templateUrl: '/templates/instructors.html', controller: 'InstructorsController' });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });
}());
```

Any idea what can cause to the error above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is separate module for angular route after angular `1.2.0` release

you need to add [`angular-route.js`](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular-route.js) and dependency as,

```
angular.module("sensorManagement", ["ngResource","ngRoute"])
```

check the [DOCUMENT](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).

Answer (score 1):

you missed injecting angular-route in your module definition

```
 angular.module('sensorManagement', ['ngRoute'])
```